# Powershell working with active directory command is working outside of the function but not inside a function

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am writing a function in PowerShell to automate the active directory. When executing the commands independently, it is working very fine, but it is not working when I am making a function.

```
Function addMember($parent, $child){
    $parentObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$parent'" -ErrorAction Continue | select -ExpandProperty ObjectId
    $childObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$child'" -ErrorAction Continue | select -ExpandProperty ObjectId

    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $parentObjectID -RefObjectId $childObjectID
}


addMember('Main', 'Child')

Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroups 
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'displayName' of resource 'Group'.
RequestId: 0ab4dc0e-0492-427c-8c86-df6cb7d4e7b6
DateTimeStamp: Tue, 06 Jul 2021 08:07:17 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:3 char:22
+ ... dObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$child'" -Error ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADGroup], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGroup
 
Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:5 char:38
+     Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $parentObjectID -RefObjectId $ch ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-AzureADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.AddGroupMember
```

Is it a problem of variable?

Comment: `eq` should be `-eq`

Comment: I tried using -eq it didn't work.
+ ... dObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$child'" -Erro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADGroup], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGroup
 
Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by calling the function by

addMember 'Main' 'Child'